# How to Tell If User Is a Regular User or an OpenAuth user with ASP.Net SimpleMembership?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetopenauth

Is there a built in function to tell if a user is a regular user or an openauth user? I'm using the built in simple membership provider for .net 4.5. I know I can check the UsersOpenAuthAccounts table myself, but I was just wondering if there is already a function built in for .net to do this.

My OpenAuth User doesn't have a local password, so the user will always use their openauth credentials to log in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(userid)`. Returns Boolean.